# Unable to connect to Cloud SQL from sails mysql

Tags: google-app-engine, sails.js, google-cloud-sql

I have a sails js app running on App Engine and a Cloud SQL instance that App Engine is supposed to talk to. I am using the following configuration with Sails v1.0 app:

```
adapter: 'sails-mysql',
socketPath: `/cloudsql/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}`,
user: process.env.SQL_USER,
password: process.env.SQL_PASSWORD,
database: 'parsley'
```

All of the env variables are passed correctly but I still get this error:

```
name=AdapterError, adapterMethodName=create, modelIdentity=admin, name=Exception, code=badConnection, exit=badConnection, errno=ECONNREFUSED, code=ECONNREFUSED
```

Comment: What kind of SQL are you using? So far I am aware some versions don't support App Engine connectivity

Comment: @Ggrimaldo I am using Google's cloud SQL - https://cloud.google.com/sql/ It's MySQL 2nd Gen 5.7

Comment: Hmm. This issue is indeed very puzzling. 

How do you pass the environment variables, with "export" command or inside app.yaml?

Comment: I pass env variables inside app.yaml - that's what Google mentions in the docs and those env variables are getting passed properly because I can see them in the logs.

Comment: Seems there is an additional environment variable which does modify where is the socket read from. Setting:

    NODE_ENV = production  

may help to fix the issue? there are some links that suggest this [1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/issues/104) [2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/blob/master/2-structured-data/books/model-cloudsql.js#L27)

Comment: The example in 2 has a condition to check for NODE_ENV=production but I don't understand why should that be mandatory. Can I not run apps in development mode using Cloud SQL?

Comment: So far I've been checking into the documentation, it looks like the Cloud SQL Proxy has been designed specially for testing purpouses.   
  
As in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) stands; "The Cloud SQL Proxy provides secure access to your Cloud SQL Second Generation instances without having to whitelist IP addresses or configure SSL.". It makes sense then that the server denies the connectivity with  "ECONNREFUSED" error messages.

Comment: But when both App Engine (which has pre-configured SSL) and the Cloud SQL instance are in the same project, it is supposed to white list the App Engine connection automatically which doesn't happen.

Comment: I am with GCP support. I have tried to reproduce the issue but I have not been able to. I have found this: "Once deployed, your application uses the Cloud SQL Proxy that is built in to the App Engine runtime environment to communicate with your Cloud SQL instance. " in [Cloud SQL for MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql) official doc, what you already mentioned. At this point I suggest you to open a support case, if you can, so we can have a deeper look into your issue, with more tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing  the code using the Cloud Shell and using a Cloud SQL Proxy:

1. Start the Cloud SQL Proxy in a Cloud Shell tab and leave the tab opened
2. Open a new tab. Try to connect from App Engine to Cloud SQL.

As described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#how-works):

> Your application communicates with the proxy with the standard
>   database protocol used by your database. The proxy uses a secure
>   tunnel to communicate with its companion process running on the
>   server.

If you don't leave the Cloud SQL Proxy running in a tab, the secure tunnel is not created and is not possible to access Cloud SQL.

There are other issues that can cause this problem but according to the research I did "googling" the error, this looks like the most common.

Comment: I am not testing the code using Cloud SQL Proxy - I believe this is required only when connecting from your local environment. But in this case, my app is running on Google App Engine.